# The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit error in java?

Tags: java, static, initialization

Hi I am trying to initialize 4 string arrays of length 10,100,1000,10000 and these arrays are like

```
array1={"0","1",..."9"} 
array2={"00","01",..."99"} 
array3={"000","001",..."999"} 
array4={"0000","0001",..."9999"}
```

But I am getting the error of **The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit**

how can I initialize my arrays?

Also note that loading it from file is not an option for me :(

Comment: There are older and fouler things than Orcs in the deep places of the world.

Comment: Maybe you should post the problem you are trying to solve.  There will be a better way.

Comment: @krock i want to do some mapping in teradata java udfs for which i need to initialize my arrays hardcodeidly

Comment: It maybe better solved by writing a method that takes an int argument and returns the string value that would have been at that array index.

Comment: I can just see one of the Java guys going: "65KB ought to be enough for anybody"...  one would think people learn from past mistakes... Yay for work-arounds... How lame...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Constant array in are initialized in java bytecode by loading each value from the constant pool and assigning it to the corresponding array index. This takes several bytes of code per array element. The size of a jvm method is limited to 65535 bytes since its length is stored in the class file using a 16 bit number.

In the case where the values can not be easily calculated in a loop, you could break the initialization into separate static functions:

```
static {
    array1 = getValuesForArray1();
    ...
}

private static String[] getValuesForArray1() {
    ...
}
```

If there is a pattern to the initialization values its of course better to calculate the values on the fly.

Comment: thanks Jörn for your help..it seems to be the solution for my problem

Answer (score 7):

Use `for` loops. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    array1[i] = String.valueOf(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

It maybe better solved by writing a method that takes an int argument and returns the string value that would have been at that array index.  Here it is using String.format and specifying the left padding length:

```
private static String getValue(int index, int stringLength) {
    return String.format("%0" + stringLength + "d", index);
}
```