# How to initialize a large constant array in Java elegantly?

Tags: java, android

My question is related to the error message discussed e.g. here: [The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit error in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10207388/4974726)

In a class I need a 2-dimensional array with about 4000 `short` constants which were expensively pre-estimated in a different software. I decided to initialize it like this:

```
private static final short[][] DataTable = {
    {32767,32767,32537,32260,31957},
    {14485,14441,14393,14338,14277,14210,14135,14052,13960},
    // Many more lines here ...
    {   60,   67,   75,   84,   95,  106,  119,  133}
}
```

But due to the above error this was not possible. So after stackoverflow search I found the above question. Inspired by an answer I changed the code like so:

```
private static final short[][] DataTable = new short[180][];
static {
    initializeA();
    initializeB();
}
private static void initializeA() {
    DataTable[0] = new short[]{32767,32767,32537,32260,31957};
    DataTable[1] = new short[]{14485,14441,14393,14338,14277,14210,14135,14052,13960};
    // Many more lines here ...
}
private static void initializeB() {
    DataTable[138] = new short[]{   60,   67,   75,   84,   95,  106,  119,  133};
    // Many more lines follow ...
}
```

The 2nd solution works but obviously there are some shortcomings:

1. I had to know the number of rows and explicitly enumerate them
2. It's much less neatly arranged in the source

**Is there a more elegant way in Java to initialize the data?**

Comment: Why don't you use `ArrayList class` ?

Comment: Load the data from a file?

Comment: In which format do you get the pre-estimated values from the other software? As @oraclecertifiedprofessional suggested, try to read them from a file, instead of hardcoding the values in a class file.

Comment: How the values are distributed in the different sub-arrays? Seems they have different lengths.

Comment: @oracle where is the size limit? You surely wouldn't load `private static final short[][] DataTable = {{1, 5, 7}, {5, 4, 8, 9}}` from file.

Comment: @SubOptimal the values come as Strings. It is easy to format their output as Java code. And yes, the rows have different length.

Comment: @redsymbolman If it's easy to format the output as Java code, then go for a solution similar to the one from laune. The `List` ensures the dynamic length in one dimension, the size of the `short[]` is defined by the values in the `add(1,2,3...)` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this using 8000 ints and it compiles (Java 7 and 8).

```
static List<short[]> a = new ArrayList<>();
static void add( int... row ){
    short[] srow = new short[row.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < row.length; ++i ){ srow[i] = (short)row[i]; }
    a.add( srow );
}
static {
   add(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19);
   add(...)
}
```

You can take an short[][] from the List.

Although, using `List<List<Integer>>` shouldn't be a problem. An x.get(i,j) isn't much more inconvenient to write than a[i,j] - you just need a minimal class wrapper containing the list and the get method.

This also compiles:

```
static List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>();
static void add( Integer... row ){
     a.add( Arrays.asList( row ) );
}
static {
    add(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19);
```

For easy access, simply use

```
class TwoDim {
    static List<List<Integer>> a = ...
    static int get(int i, int j){ return a.get(i).get(j); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Then take the size which is necessary to get the above mentioned error. I don't use Java 8 yet. Your solution is _more elegant_ indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

Java `ArrayList` a dynamic array which grows in size as and when you add items. So the `size`? forget about it.

How do I use it in my case?

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(32767, 32767, 32537, 32260, 31957));
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList(
            Arrays.asList(14485, 14441, 14393, 14338, 14277, 14210, 14135, 14052, 13960));

    System.out.println(list1 + " " + list1.size());
    System.out.println(list2 + " " + list2.size());
```

---

How to create a 2-Dimensional Array in an ArrayList.

There's a simple technique to do so.

Create an ArrayList() of type ArrayList()

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList(
            Arrays.asList(14485, 14441, 14393, 14338, 14277, 14210, 14135, 14052, 13960));
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add(list1);
myList.add(list2);

for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < myList.get(i).size(); ++j)
        System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + myList.get(i).get(j));
```

Comment: Thank you. Your example not really fits to the 2-dimensional case which I raised in my question. And I don't see easily how to transfer it to my case. Would you help me with a 2-dimensional example? Also, the access is interesting. In my case it was just `DataTable[i][j]`

Comment: @redsymbolman I updated the answer so that you can use a 2-d representation. Have a look and tell me if that is what you wanted.