# Is there a way to split up or reduce the size of my string array?

Tags: java, arrays, xtext

I'm using Xtext to generate a parser for my language. But after the java files are generated, i am getting errors :*"The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit"* in my lexer classes. 
I found out it's due to one String Array being 13k lines long.

The code is automatically generated so I have no real control about how that array is used.

I tried moving it into a separate class, but the Array itself is too big for the 65k limit.

```
package com.intercope.analysis1.parser.antlr.internal;

public class ExternalArrays {

    static final String[] DFA28_transitionS = {" {
            "\11\76\2\75\2\76\1\75\22\76\1\75\1\10\1\73\1\65\3\76\1\74\1\43\1\44\1\61\1\57\1\45\1\60\1\76\1\46\2\70\1\64\2\70\1\66\1\67\3\70\1\76\1\36\1\6\1\5\1\7\2\76\1\3\1\52\1\16\1\20\1\24\1\31\1\37\1\72\1\34\2\72\1\25\1\23\1\22\1\1\1\14\1\72\1\21\1\27\1\32\1\12\1\63\1\41\3\72\3\76\1\71\1\72\1\76\1\4\1\51\1\15\1\17\1\56\1\30\1\40\1\72\1\33\2\72\1\50\1\53\1\72\1\2\1\13\1\72\1\35\1\26\1\47\1\11\1\62\1\42\3\72\1\54\1\76\1\55\uff82\76",
            "\1\103\2\uffff\1\101\1\uffff\1\77\1\102\3\uffff\1\100", ...};
}
```

Since these are values depending on my lexer grammar I cant generate them using a function.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this is appreciated ^^

---

**Edit:** An excerpt from the array:

```
       "\1\u0310\1\uffff\1\u0313\7\uffff\1\u0312\1\uffff\1\u030f\2\uffff\1\u0311",
            "\1\u0314",
            "\1\u0315",
            "\1\u0316",
            "\1\u0317",
            "\1\u0318",
            "\1\u0319",
            "\12\104\7\uffff\32\104\4\uffff\1\104\1\uffff\32\104",
            "\1\u031b",
            "\12\104\7\uffff\32\104\4\uffff\1\104\1\uffff\32\104",
            "\12\104\7\uffff\32\104\4\uffff\1\104\1\uffff\32\104",
            "\1\u031e",
            "\1\u031f",
            "\1\u0320",
            "\1\u0321",
            "\1\u0322",
            "\12\104\7\uffff\32\104\4\uffff\1\104\1\uffff\32\104",
            "\1\u0324",
            "\12\104\7\uffff\32\104\4\uffff\1\u0325\1\uffff\32\104",
            "\12\104\7\uffff\32\104\4\uffff\1\104\1\uffff\32\104",
            "\1\u0328",
           "\1\u032c\1\uffff\1\u032b\12\uffff\1\u0329\2\uffff\1\u032a\1\uffff\1\u032d",
            "\1\u032e",
            "\1\u032f",
            "\1\u0330",
            "\1\u0331",
            "\1\u0332",
            "\1\u0333",
            "\1\u0334",
            "\1\u0335",
            "\1\u0336",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit error in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207388/the-code-for-the-static-initializer-is-exceeding-the-65535-bytes-limit-error-in)

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk I sadly cant generate these values with a function. So not a duplicate of the question you flagged.

Comment: The code is automatically generated but maybe you can modify it by putting the value of `DFA28_transitionS` in a file that you load on startup ?

Comment: I know this isn't particularly helpful, but it looks like this is a currently unresolved issue with Xtext.  Here's [the bug report](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/issues/933)

Comment: @Jordan Ah thanks. Good to know im, not the only one having this problem.

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk I guess so. I don't really know how to go about that though.

Comment: Do you have your code on github or something ?

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk No. And sadly I can't share it.
What filetype/library would you recommend for storing and reading the array?

Comment: Looks like you can store it as shown in your questions, comma separated lines. You can then parse easily with any standard file reading libraries, read it line by line and add each line to the array.

Comment: did you enable class splitting?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich No. How would I do that? Couldn't find anything online :/
Edit: Found out how still have the same bug though. Only now I can't pinpoint what causes the class to be this large.